# How to combine a records relationship with another models relationship of the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Consider this example in Rails 6.1 with postgresql:

An `organization` has `users` & `pictures`

An `item` has_and_belongs_to_many `pictures` and belongs_to an `organization`

A `user` has_and_belongs_to_many `items` and belongs_to an `organization`, has relationship `has_many :pictures, through: :items`

`pictures` belong_to an `organization` & has_and_belongs_to_many `users`

`pictures` can only be viewed by an admin of an organization and those users have have/belong to them. So for a user doing something as simple as `current_user.pictures` will show them all the pictures they are allowed to view.
(in this example an admin uploads pictures and shares them with certain users)

This is where my question comes in:

Pictures can also be marked as `public`, which would allow any user to view them in their list. So essentially I want combine `organization.pictures.where(public: true)` and `current_user.pictures` (which uses a join table) into one query and also easily add any sql order or pagination.

I could simply use concatenation `current_user.pictures + organization.pictures.where(public: true)` but that returns an array and then I'd have to use array methods to sort and paginate, which is undesirable.

What other options do I have? I can't seem to get an `.or` to work either.

Update: A solution I had figured would 'work' originally does and is what I'm going with for now, to pluck the ids from the two joins tables `has_many :pictures, through: :items`, but I am still curious of a better way;
In the user model:

```
def viewable_pictures
  pictures_ids = pictures.pluck(:id)
  organization.pictures.public_to_daycare.or(Picture.where(id: pictures_ids))
end
```

Comment: You say you can't get `or` to work - what have you tried? Does `organization.pictures.where(public: true).or(current_user.pictures)` not do what you want?

Comment: What @JohnP said.You could even implement this as a `User` instance method e.g. `def viewable_pictures; pictures.or(organization.pictures.where(public:true))` better still add a scope to `Picture` for this e.g. `scope :public, -> {where(public: true)}` then it would be `pictures.or(organization.pictures.public)` and you can call as `current_user.viewable_pictures`

Comment: I realized I forgot a layer of relationships in between user and items. I updated my post. I think thats why I've been having trouble with something like @JohnP & @engineersmnky suggested with `organization.pictures.where(public: true).or(current_user.pictures)` (I've since tried that and it only returns the users pictures)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would think the query from the Picture model instead of the organization object. Something like:

```rb
Picture.where(public: true, organization_id: organization.id).or(Picture.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

Comment: This may be on the right track, however, the Picture model does not relate to the user model or even the item model directly with a foreign id, but instead uses a joins table to the item model, which then uses another join table to users.